# Relationship between $x^{p-1} - a$ and $x^p - ax - b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

I am in a finite field with characteristic $p$. I also have a polynomial $g = x^p - ax - b$ where $a$ is not the identity. The question is, if $E$ is the split field of the polynomial $g$, is it also a split field of $h = x^{p-1} -a$? I tried to divide, but I don't think $h$ divides $g$. I also tried to see if $g$ can be reduced, but that depends on $a$. Besides these two, I also know that $x^{q-1} = 1$ where $q$ is the number of elements in the field. But that doesn't work here. What else should I try?

Comment: "I am in a finite field with characteristic $p$." Wow – could you send me a postcard?

Comment: @GerryMyerson My native language is not English. I apologize.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Or is that a joke?

Comment: A joke. I was taking literally something you meant figuratively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably I can assume that $a\neq0$.

Yes, the splitting field of $h$ is included in the splitting field of $g$.

The key is that the polynomial
$$
f(x)=x^p-ax= xh(x)=g(x)+b
$$
is a so called *linearized polynomial*. In other words, 
$$
f(x+y)=(x+y)^p-a(x+y)=x^p+y^p-ax-ay=f(x)+f(y)
$$
for all $x,y$ in any extension field.
So if $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{p-1}$ are the zeros of $g(x)$ (they are distinct, because $g'(x)=-a\neq0$), then
$$
f(x_i-x_0)=f(x_i)-f(x_0)=[g(x_i)-b]-[g(x_0)-b]=-b-(-b)=0
$$
for all $i=1,2,\ldots,p-1$. As $x_i-x_0\neq0$ and
$$
h(x_i-x_0)=\frac{f(x_i-x_0)}{x_i-x_0}
$$
it follows that the zeros of $h(x)$ are the elements $x_i-x_0$, $i=1,2,\ldots,p-1$, that manifestly belong to any splitting field of $g(x)$.

Comment: My knee-jerk reaction was to bring $g(x)$ into Artin-Schreier form by a linear substitution. IOW look for an element $\lambda$ such that $g(\lambda x)$ is a constant multiple of $x^p-x-c$. It turns out that for this to work, $\lambda$ needs to be a zero of $h$. The zeros of AS-polynomials differ from each other by an element of the prime field, so we then get an idea for the difference of zeros of $g$, and this answer pops out.

Comment: Observe that the answer is (obviously it has to) independent of choice of $x_0$. This is because the zeros of $g(x)$ form a coset of the additive subgroup formed by the zeros of $f(x)$.